# Converting symbology from ArcInfo Workstation to ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, symbology, arcgis-9.3, arcinfo-workstation

I was using UNIX based ArcInfo Workstation software and I have many Data in a coverage file.

I need this files to change to shapes to use in ArcGIS Desktop software.

By exporting it brings only the data.

How can I bring those symbols for all (.txt, .lin, .shd and .mrk) which are created in ArcInfo Workstation to use them in ArcGIS Desktop 9.3?

Answer (score 1):

[Migrating from ArcInfo™ Workstation: An ESRI ® Technical Paper • December 2002](http://downloads.esri.com/support/whitepapers/ao_/Migrating_from_ArcInfo_Workstation.pdf) says on page 6:

> Symbology: all ArcInfo Workstation symbols—plus many more—are
>   available through style sets. A symbol converter is also available for
>   converting custom ArcInfo symbol sets.

I do not recall having ever used or seen that symbol convertor but if you are not able to locate it then I recommend contacting your local [Esri support](http://support.esri.com).