# Convert SHD files to CLR or more modern color ramp format

Tags: arcgis-pro, color-ramp

I have a legacy SHD file (from Arc/Info) that contain color ramp information that I would like to use to symbolize a raster layer in ArcGIS Pro. I have access to an Arc/Info installation and am able to print the color values in the SHD file, but there are dozens of steps that I do not want to have to transcribe manually. Is there a way to export these files to a format that can be read into ArcGIS?

This question addresses the topic generally for symbols but in this case I am specifically interested in SHD files: [Converting symbology from ArcInfo Workstation to ArcGIS Desktop?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/149269/converting-symbology-from-arcinfo-workstation-to-arcgis-desktop)

An alternative, if no export capability exists directly, might be a method to automatically construct an ArcGIS Pro CLR file based on the text dump of the SHD file, so a method to do that would also answer my question.

Here is an example of the text dump from the SHD file (it continues for several dozen rows):

[image: Text dump of SHD file]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having researched this further, the CLR format is a simple text file format that can be constructed directly using the output shown in my original question: https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/raster-and-images/creating-a-color-map-clr-file.htm

Steps to create the .clr file:

1. Dump the text output shown above to a file
2. Convert the CMYK colors to RGB, either using a formula or a website such as https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/color/cmyk-to-rgb.html
3. Export the RGB values to a new file bluegray2rust.clr in the format shown in the link above.

There may also be a .clr export feature available in Arc/Info, but I have not found it.